# помогите с htaccess, нужно убрать www и переслать на index.php

Tags: .htaccess

был код который работал:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

Пересылал все на index.php, а там уже подгружалась нужная страница.
но если в начале домена пишешь www, шрифы все отваливаются, хочу убрать www, т.е дописать что то типа этого:

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
#RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%1/$1 [L,R=permanent]
```

но чтоб это работало одновременно, помогите пожалуйста, меняю L С NC выдает ошибки(

Сейчас:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
# чтоб работали шрифты на сайте
<FilesMatch "\.(css|otf|eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg)$|^$">
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
#Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Если код `RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]` действительно работал, то пока не вижу причин, чтобы он не работал для любого алиаса домена (хоть www, хоть zzz), при условии, что это один и тот же виртуалхост с одним и тем же DocumentRoot. Покажите весь htaccess, который сейчас реально работает.

Comment: вообще работает  и так и так, проблема в шрифте FontAwesome
когда заходишь на www.мой_сайт.ru он (шрифт FontAwesome) не работает, когда заходишь без www, вот так мой_сайт.ru он срабатывает
поэтому и хочу сделать пересылку на сайт без www

Comment: выше в вопрос дописал код который сейчас в htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Давайте так попробуем:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.my-site\.ru
RewriteRule (.*)          http://my-site.ru [L,R=301]
RewriteRule (.*)          index.php [L]
```